# Why do I get an ambiguous occurrence error when I define an instance?

Tags: haskell, syntax, typeclass

I have a type `Foo` and want to make it an instance of `Show`, so that I can use it in GHCi:

```
data Foo = Foo

instance Show Foo where
show Foo = "Foo"
```

However, when I try to use it, I get an ambiguous occurrence error:

```
ghci> show Foo
<interactive>:4:1:
    Ambiguous occurrence `show'
    It could refer to either `Main.show', defined at Foo.hs:4:1
                          or `Prelude.show',
                             imported from `Prelude' at Foo.hs:1:1
                             (and originally defined in `GHC.Show')
```

Why? I just defined the function that belongs to a typeclass, didn't I?

Comment: Note: this question is, just [like my other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35855170/why-shouldnt-i-mix-tabs-and-spaces), intended to be a minimal generic variant of one of the more frequently asked Haskell questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Indent your instance bindings.

---

Enable warnings and you will notice that you didn't implement the *instance operation* `show`, but instead a *new* function with the same name:

```
Foo.hs:3:10: Warning:
    No explicit implementation for
      either `showsPrec' or `Prelude.show'
    In the instance declaration for `Show Foo'
```

Therefore there are now two `show`s. `Main.show` (the one you've just accidentally defined) and `Prelude.show` (the one by the class you've wanted to use).

We can verify that by looking at their types (although we need to fully qualify their names):

```
ghci> :t Main.show
Main.show :: Foo -> [Char]
ghci> :t Prelude.show
Prelude.show :: Show a => a -> String
```

That's because your `where` bindings need to be indented, just like you would indent them in a usual function. Even a single space is enough:

```
instance Show Foo where
 show Foo = "Foo"
```

Remember, Haskell uses whitespace to delimit blocks. Just ask yourself: when would the `where` stop otherwise?