# Parse error on input f

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create an anagram lookup in haskell, I am getting a parse error on input "f"

Here is my code

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import Data.List (sort)
import qualified Data.Map as M

type Anagrams = Map String [String]

main :: IO()
main = buildAnagrams "dictionary.txt" >>= loop
  where
    loop :: Anagrams -> IO ()
    loop anagrams = forever $ do
         putStrLn "Anagrams of..."
         getLine >>=  print . lookupAnagrams anagrams


buildAnagrams :: FilePath -> IO Anagrams
buildAnagrams = fmap (foldr f M.empty . lines ) . readFile
  where 
     f :: String -> Anagrams -> Anagrams
     f s = M.insertWith (++) (sort s) [s]

lookupAnagrams :: Anagrams -> String -> [String]
lookupAnagrams anagrams str =   
    case M.Lookup(sort str) anagrams of
        Nothing -> []
        Just XS -> XS
```

the error is on the line f s = M.insertWith

Comment: It would be better if you posted the exact error you are getting alongside the code.

Comment: Don't mark as answers as resolved by editing them - I've rolled back the change.

Comment: Sorry first time posting here, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 errors with your code, neither of which is a parse error. Error messages differ between compiler versions, so it is hard for me to know exactly what you see.

These are the errors I had to fix to have your code compile:

1. Add the line `import Control.Monad (forever)`.
2. Fix the identifier case in the expression `case M.lookup (sort str) anagrams of ...`.
3. Fix the identifier case in the line `Just xs -> xs`.

*(Overall, you could also replace that `case` with a `fromMaybe`. It would be idiomatic and concise.)*

In Haskell you distinguish the sort of an identifier by the case of the first character. If the identifier starts with a capital letter, it would mean it is either a data constructor, a type constructor or a module name. For ordinary values *(and type variables)*, you always start with lower case.

I hope this helps you. Let me know if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

You have a tab character forming part of the whitespace on the line that you indicated the parse error is on. Precisely, in the code in your post above, you have this line (`»` is tab, `·` is space):

```
··»·····f :: ...
```

Haskell is a [whitespace sensitive language](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation) - in particular, it's a lot easier and less error-prone to just [use spaces instead of tabs, and mixing them rarely works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35855170/why-shouldnt-i-mix-tabs-and-spaces).

Replacing any tabs with spaces should fix your parse error - if your editor has a "tabs to spaces" conversion option, that's a good thing to enable. To fix the other errors present in your code, Ignat Insarov has already given a good answer.

Comment: How did you find out? I passed the code through `xxd` and see no occurences of a `0x09` character.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov It's not shown in the code in the post, but if you hit [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49828678/edit) and skip your cursor along the whitespace before that line, it'll jump 2 spaces instead of one. The "ask question" dialog doesn't easily allow tabs to be entered directly, so it's extremely likely the OP pasted the tab in from their code - and it matches the error message they get. I used to have this issue a lot, so I'm uncomfortably aware of the possibility.

Comment: Oh. I see. Thanks!